# android - upload file from app to server using php

Tags: php, android

I followed tutorial at here :
[tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)

It's working. I got response code 200. But, There is no my uploaded file in server. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: please add some of your code

Comment: @DirkHorsten It's exactly same as `tutorial` page except server url and upload file

Comment: That is a bad example as it does not read the returned page. So you never know if php script returned success or fail. But you can add code for it. Google for readinputstreamtostring.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have given `777` (Read Write permissions) to your uploads folder.

Comment: I gave 777 permission. But, still same problem.

Comment: What is value in `serverResponseMessage` in your logs?

Comment: It's `OK`. `HTTP Response is : OK: 200`

Comment: It should print `success` according to `echo "success";` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39381155/4324320

This question is same like the tagged question. You can find the solution in this page.

Thank you.